# Vk bot, пожалуйста помогите, у меня проблема!

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

```
authorize.method ('messages.send', {'user_id': sender, 'message': message, 'random_id':})
```

Всё верно? просто пишет что знак : то там то там везде ааа у меня голова кипитится

Comment: У вас после random_id нет значения после : Почитайте про формат JSON, что бы понимать, с чем вы работаете

Answer (score 0):

В вашем исходном коде отсутствует значение для `random_id`. Функция `vk_api.utils.get_random_id()` генерирует случайный `random_id`, который используется, чтобы избежать повторной отправки одинаковых сообщений.